# possible to setup Static IP addresses on your private network(laptop wifi hotspot)?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, static-ip, hotspot

- My pc uses a LAN to connect to the internet and I have set up a wifi hotspot on my pc(windows) so that my mobile devices can use that network to use pc's internet access. so far it works.
- But i need to set a static IP address just only for one mobile device since it has a problem with DHCP(Cyanogen12; after a while device is unable to access the internet even though it is connected to the wifi).
- How to set a static IP addresses on your hotspot network(windows 8.1) so that mobile device can use static IP instead of DHCP?

(If allowing one static IP address and DHCP all at the same time is not possible, i'm ready to use only static IPs to all my mobile devices)

Comment: Just set the static IP address on your Cyanogen12 device. You don't have to do anything on Windows.

Comment: i tried several static IPs. but it doesn't get connected to internet(though it connects to the network)

Comment: Hmm, it worked in Win7...

Comment: Tried again. no luck. that's why i thought maybe i have to specify the static ip(i enter on the phone) has to be specified on pc hotspot

Comment: Can the phone and PC ping each other? I've not checked under Win 8.1 but there was never previously any requirement.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq
what you suggested earlier was right. i have been trying the wrong gateway(ethernet instead of hotspot) all this time. sorry for bothering. Thanks you (Y)